# rails search across many tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have a some what complex search query that I cannot seem to resolve. I have three tables.

Items, Regions, Type

**Schema**

```
create_table "Items"
 t.integer  "item_id"
 t.string   "name",
 t.datetime "created_at",
 t.datetime "updated_at",
 t.integer  "year",
 t.float    "price",

create_table "Regions"
 t.integer  "region_id"
 t.float    "name",

create_table "Type"
 t.integer  "item_id"
 t.float    "name",
 t.integer  "item_number"
```

And i'm looking at creating a search function based on the above scheme to output results and then comparing the price of two items.

**View**

```
<%= form_tag vpc_search_path do |f| %>

<h5>Select Item One</h5>
<%= select_tag :item_one, options_from_collection_for_select(@item, "item_id", "name"), include_blank: false %>

<h5>Select Item Two</h5>
<%= select_tag "variety_two", options_from_collection_for_select(@item, "item_id", "name"), include_blank: false %>

<% @type.each do |i| %>
<div class="checkbox inline"><%= check_box_tag :type, i.name, {:checked => true} %>
</div>
<% end %>

<% @years.each do |y| %>
<%= check_box_tag :year, y.year %> <%= y.year %></br>
<% end %>

<% @regions.each do |r| %>
<%= check_box_tag :regions, r.region_id, {:checked => true} %> <%= r.name %></br>
<% end %>

<%= submit_tag "Compare" %>
<% end %>
```

I want to be able to search matching the 'name' in 'Items' then output the average price based on regions, types and years. One problem I seem to be having is that the search only recognises the 'Select Item Two' option and not both.

```
Result View

<h2>Item Results</h2>

We found <%= @count %> items that matched your options, spanning <%= @years %> years and <%= @regions %> regions

<table class="table">
 <th></th>
 <th><%= @item_one %></th>
 <th><%= @item_two %></th>
 <th>Difference</th>
<tr>
<td>Price</td>
 <% @comparison.each do |v| %>
<td><%= v.price1 %></td>
<td><%= v.price2 %></td>
<td><%= v.price1 - v.price2 %></td>
</tr>
</table>
<% end %>
```

**Controller**

```
def index
    all = Items.select(:item_id)
    @item = Item.where(:item_id => all).order('item_name DESC')
    @years = Item.select('DISTINCT year') 
    @regions = Region.all
    @type = Type.select('DISTINCT name').order('name ASC')
  end

  def search
   @comparison = Item.where(:item_id => params[:item_one], :item_id => params[:item_two], :year => params[:year])
   @count = @comparison.count
   @years = @comparison.count(params[:year])
   @item_one = Item.where('item_id = ?', params[:item_one]).group('name').select('name')
   @item_two = Item.where('item_id = ?', params[:item_two]).group('name').select('name')
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

> "I want to be able to search matching the 'name' in 'Items' then
>   output  the average price based on regions, types and years".

Maybe the relationship should be something like this.

Item-> belongs to Regions
Item-> belongs to Type(s)

Then if want to search item, given the name and year using only one query.

```
Item.select("i.name").from("Items i, Regions r, Types t").
where("i.region_id = r.region_id").
where("i.type_id = t.type_id").
where("i.name=?", params[:name]).
where("i.year=?", params[:year])
```

Tip* 
Ruby on Rails follow linguistic convention therefore it would be better to rename your "Type" table to "Types"
as model represents a single entity, whereas a database table consists of many entity.